# Tracing systemd's target execution order

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I'm trying to understand Systemd's operations when the system boot ups. In my humble understanding, normally the first target to be initialized is `/usr/lib/systemd/user/default.target`, the below targets taken from Ubuntu:

`default.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Default
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=basic.target
After=basic.target
AllowIsolate=yes
```

`default.target` requires and runs after `basic.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Basic System
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Wants=sockets.target timers.target paths.target
After=sockets.target timers.target paths.target
```

`sockets.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sockets
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
```

`timers.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Timers
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)

DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target
```

`paths.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Paths
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
```

So Systemd goes to determine the dependency of the dependency and the dependency of the dependency and so on, but we reached a dead end, how? Assuming that everything went fine in the whole process, that is all dependencies for `defaul.target` were determined and initialized, we still need `multi-user.target`, `sysinit.target` and other targets, all the above target mention nothing about those targets.

How Systemd determines which targets to be initialized and which ones should be ignored?

Comment: The default.target will be called from /etc/systemd/system and not /usr/lib/systemd/system. The entry in /etc will have a link to the init target you have set systemd up to run in as default i.e. multi-user.target. /etc/systemd/system/default.target will therefore have a link to /usr/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.

Comment: @RamanSailopal There's no `/usr/lib/systemd/system` on my machine running Ubuntu. And `/etc/systemd/system/default.target` doesn't exist either.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm running Kubuntu 17.04. I discovered `default.target` in `/lib/systemd/system/default.target`. I don't really know where there are two of them. This is the one that requires `multi-user.target` and wants`display-manager.service`.

Comment: /usr/lib is normally for user defined systemd files and /lib for package managed files. I haven't got a Kubuntu system available but my Centos and SuSE systems all have /etc/systemd directories.